# Counting from first item, ignore counting within next 30 days

Tags: mysql, count, sum, conditional-statements

I have a set of subscriptions which last 30 days each from the purchase of the first item during the period

```
PID    |     Date Purchased     |   User ID      | Owner ID
=======+========================+================+==============
1      |  1/1/2011              | 1              |  1
2      |  2/1/2011              | 1              |  1
3      |  19/1/2011             | 1              |  1
4      |  3/2/2011              | 1              |  1
5      |  5/1/2011              | 2              |  1
6      |  9/2/2011              | 2              |  1
```

I have a table containing a billing cycle

```
Owner ID | DATEBEGIN        | DATEEND  
=========+==================+============
1        | 1/2/2011         | 2/3/2011
```

So for each owner id I would need to categorize periods into 30 day intervals before the `dateend` value. I need to count the purchases by unique user id's from the first purchase, and 'book' the next 30 days (don't count during this period), and count the first after that.

So for instance PID (PurchaseID) 1 on 1/1/2011, 'books' the next 30 days so they are ignored.
But this falls into a previous billing period, and the remainder is carried into the next
so 3/30 in the first, and 27/30 in the next, (sales on 2/1/2011, 19/1/2011 are ignored, but on 3/2/2011 isn't booked so it is counted)

```
Owner ID   | User ID   | PeriodBegin     | PeriodEnd    | Usage    | Comment
===========+===========+=====+===========+===============+=========+================
1          | 1         | 3/12/2010       | 1/1/2011     | 3/30     | 
1          | 1         | 2/1/2011        | 1/2/2011     | 27/30    |
1          | 1         | 2/2/2011        | 4/3/2011     | 29/30    |
1          | 1         | 5/3/2011        | 4/4/2011     | 1/30     |
1          | 2         | 2/2/2011        | 4/3/2011     | 25/30    |
1          | 2         | 5/3/2011        | 4/4/2011     | 5/30     |
```

Eventually I aggregate these into the next

```
Owner ID  | PeriodBegin     | PeriodEnd    | Usage    |
==========+=================+==============+==========+
1         | 3/12/2010       | 1/1/2011     | 3/30     | 
1         | 2/1/2011        | 1/2/2011     | 27/30    |
1         | 2/2/2011        | 4/3/2011     | 54/30    |
1         | 5/3/2011        | 4/4/2011     | 6/30     |
```

So I'm stuck trying to figure out how to tell MySQL to ignore the values within 30 days of the first purchase and then to count the ones after this 'booked' period ends.

To make it easier to understand I've made an analogy to mp3 subscriptions. The first table can be purchases from record company to distributors (which each have their own owner ids and multiple accounts for each end user (user id).
So within their first purchase of an mp3, they have a 30 days subscription service to download unlimited mp3s. The second last table is their billing schedule. So its unfair to charge a full days worth of mp3s if they buy a song 1 day before the billing period ends so it has to be split up into pieces, and the balance charged the following month.